# Generating resource_bundle_accessor, Type 'Bundle' has no member 'module'

Tags: swift, xcode, bundle, swift-package-manager

Some times Xcode can not determine the `module` parameter in the Bundle.

> Type 'Bundle' has no member 'module'

My investigations show that SPM generates an extension on the module (some times) for this property automatically in a file called *`resource_bundle_accessor`* like:

```
import class Foundation.Bundle

private class BundleFinder {}

extension Foundation.Bundle {
    /// Returns the resource bundle associated with the current Swift module.
    static var module: Bundle = {
        let bundleName = "ABUIKit_ABStyleKit"

        let candidates = [
            // Bundle should be present here when the package is linked into an App.
            Bundle.main.resourceURL,

            // Bundle should be present here when the package is linked into a framework.
            Bundle(for: BundleFinder.self).resourceURL,

            // For command-line tools.
            Bundle.main.bundleURL,
        ]

        for candidate in candidates {
            let bundlePath = candidate?.appendingPathComponent(bundleName + ".bundle")
            if let bundle = bundlePath.flatMap(Bundle.init(url:)) {
                return bundle
            }
        }
        fatalError("unable to find bundle named ABUIKit_ABStyleKit")
    }()
}
```

But sometimes it won't.  Why is that and how can I make it work automatically **again** (Without the need to manually implement that.)

Both situations happen on **Xcode 12 beta.3**

#### Update

Sometimes it shows:

> 'module' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

And it's not showing the file at all.

Comment: Where is this resource_bundle_accessor file located? I tried everything suggested in the answers and it will just not work. Might as well create it myself instead then.

Comment: No you must NOT create it yourself!!! It is autogenerated and that is the main point of the question.

Comment: I actually posted a related question here this morning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403646/swift-package-manager-with-resources-compile-errors - maybe you can spot an error in my `Package.swift` file?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

SPM generates the *`resource_bundle_accessor`* only if the corresponding target contains `resources` as the argument like:

```
    .target(
        name: "ChenzookKit",
        dependencies: ["Apollo"],
        resources: [.process("Resources")] // <- `copy` or `process` doesn't really matter 
    ),
```

<sub>Also, note that it should be a valid resource path.</sub>

## AND❗️

The project **MUST** contains `Resources` **inside** the target's Directory!

[image: Example]

## AND❗️❗️

The `Resources` **MUST** contain something and **MUST NOT** be an empty directory

## AND❗️❗️❗️

Don't forget to build (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>) the code to make the `.module` be created!

Comment: Future readers, it seems that these solutions don't work yet for Swift 5.5 and executable targets: cf. [this comment on a bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-13773?focusedCommentId=64312&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-64312) and my own experience 

Comment: It worked for me, the Resources folder must be not-empty!

Comment: I found I needed to restart Xcode for it to recognise the directory was there.

Comment: Oh the Second point needs special clarification (although the pic depicts it so nicely). The **Resources** folder needs to be inside Sources->Package Folder Name.

Answer (score 39):

If you see errors like this:

> Error: found 1 file(s) which are unhandled; explicitly declare them as resources or exclude from the target

> Type 'Bundle' has no member 'module'

Then review the following five conditions:

**1.** Check that the first line of your Package.swift declares the use of swift-tools-version:5.3 or a later version.

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3
```

**2.** Check the Resource folder is under the target folder. For instance,

```
Sources/MyTarget/Resources
Tests/MyTargetTests/Resources
```

**3.** Check that you already added at least one resource. For instance,

```
Tests/MyTargetTests/Resources/paginatedLabels.json
```

**4.** Check that you open the package by opening the file Package.swift with Xcode.

**5.** Check that the Package.swift file declares a resources element, like this:

```
.testTarget(
    name: "MyTargetTests",
    dependencies: ["MyTarget"],
    resources: [
        .process("Resources")
    ]
),
```

---

At this point, the compiler synthesized a file `resource_bundle_accessor.swift` with this content:

```swift
extension Foundation.Bundle {
    static var module: Bundle = {
...
```

To check that the file was indeed synthesized:

```sh
# is the bundle being synthesized when you build?
find ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData* -iname resource_bundle_accessor.swift
```

To load resources from the package bundle use `Bundle.module`, e.g.

```swift
UIImage(named: "share", in: Bundle.module, compatibleWith: nil)
```

To find the path to the package bundle directory:

```sh
MODULE=MyModuleName && find -E ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData -regex ".*$MODULE_$MODULE.bundle"
```

To check that the package bundle contains a particular resource, e.g. an image:

```sh
# I’m building for iPhone 12 (@3x). Is share@3x.png inside the bundle?
find ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData* -iname Assets.car -exec xcrun --sdk iphoneos assetutil --info {} \; | grep -E "share.*png"
```

---

Here is an example that uses custom directories:

```
targets: [
    .target(
        name: "Kit",
        dependencies: [],
        path: "sources/main",
        resources: [
            .process("resources")
        ]
    ),
```

where directories are:

```
Kit/
├── sources/
│   └── main/
│       ├── SourceFile.swift
│       └── resources/
│           └── file.json
└── Package.swift
```

---

If everything fails and you suspect a bug check the [bug database for SPM](https://bugs.swift.org/issues/?jql=project+%3D+SR+AND+component+%3D+%22Package+Manager%22).

Comment: The first condition solves my problem, thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

Okay I found a solution, so Swift actually generates the `Bundle.module` file

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/resource) explicitly states that you have to put your `Resources` under the folder `<project_root>/Sources/<MyTarget>/` since SPM scopes resources by target. The target definition looks then like this for my repo [SHSearchBar](https://github.com/Blackjacx/SHSearchBar/blob/swift53/Package.swift) (compare file structure on Github):

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.3
import PackageDescription


    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "SHSearchBar",
            resources: [.copy("Resources")]
        )
    ]
```

Target Folder: `<project_root>/Sources/SHSearchBar` 
Resource Folder: `<project_root>/Sources/SHSearchBar/Resources`

By the way, to build an iOS package from command line you can use this command uses the iOS 14 SDK:

```
swift build -Xswiftc "-sdk" -Xswiftc "\`xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path\`" -Xswiftc "-target" -Xswiftc "x86_64-apple-ios14.0-simulator"
```

To make my little post here complete I also want to mention that a package using the `Bundle.module` approach can be integrated in apps that run on iOS <14 too since the generated extension does not contain any new API

Comment: Don't make the mistake I did: be sure you have `// swift-tools-version:5.3` or greater at the top of your package file, instead of, say, `swift-tools-version:5.1` because it was copied from another package as a template. 

If not 5.3 or above, `Bundle` will not be generated and the error messages are not super clear.

Answer (score 3):

`Bundle.module` will only be generated by SwiftPM if the `resources` in the `Package.swift` file is not empty **and** the specified resources actually exist.

So there are **two possible reasons** why it might not work for you:

1. You don't have any `resources` specified in `Package.swift`. Fix like this:

```swift
.target(
    name: "MyLibrary",
    dependencies: [
        /* your dependencies */
    ],
    resources: [
        .copy("JsonData"),
        .process("Assets.xcassets"),
    ]
),
```

2. The specified paths don't exist or are empty.

   Fix by checking that you've actually placed your resources **inside
   the `Sources/MyLibrary`** directory. A common mistake is to place them
   directly to `Sources` or to a different targets subfolder.

Answer (score 2):

You can also expose the bundle by creating a class with static let:

```
public class YourPackageBundle {
   public static let yourPackageBundle = Bundle.module
}
```

Then you can access it in your public classes and use it:

```
public init(backgroundImage: Image? = nil,
            logoImage: Image? = nil,
            userIconImage: Image? = nil,
            userTextFieldPlaceholder:String = NSLocalizedString("global_username", bundle: YourPackageBundle.yourPackageBundle, comment: "User placeholder text")
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I've tried all the solutions and nothing helped until I've restarted Xcode.

Done on Xcode 14.0.0

Comment: @luizv it is an / the answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that the `Resources` folder exists and that it has files
2. `Bundle.module` is autogenerated by XCode when the `Resources` folder is not empty. However it is `internal`
3. Add `@testable import YourPackage` to make makes internal files in your package sources available to tests.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your `text.json` in the `Resources` folder, make sure that you have `.process("Resources/text.json")` path in your `Package.swift`

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode version 15.2:**

Inside the package description file, if your target describes the path, you don't need a Resources folder:

```
targets: [
        .target(
            name: "BackyardBirdsData",
            path: "."
        )
    ]
```

**You just have to make sure that your package already contains at least one resource (i.e. a .json file)**