# Swift Package Manager - Type 'Bundle' has no member “module” error

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

Working on implementing SPM for a framework, and got stuck on the `Type 'Bundle' has no member “module”` error.

I have seen two other recent posts about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63237395/generating-resource-bundle-accessor-type-bundle-has-no-member-module) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64400676/type-bundle-has-no-member-module), but following all the steps, it is still not working for me, no `resource_bundle_accessor` file is generated.

I asked about my Package.swift file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403646/swift-package-manager-with-resources-compile-errors/64407199), and that has been answered and resolved. For completeness here's the file:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "BioSwift",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "BioSwift",
            targets: ["BioSwift"]
        )
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "BioSwift",
            dependencies: [],
            resources: [
                  .process("Resources")
                ]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "BioSwiftTests",
            dependencies: ["BioSwift"]
        )
    ]
)
```

I get the  `Type 'Bundle' has no member “module”` error when trying to access one of the resources in the bundle:

```
public let unimodURL = Bundle.module?.url(forResource: "unimod", withExtension: "xml")
```

The project is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/koenvanderdrift/BioSwift/tree/master)

Comment: Where is the `.process("Resources")`?

Comment: Also, you MUST use `swift-tools-version:5.3` for accessing resources

Comment: Oops, I copy-pasted the wrong Package.swift - all fixed now in the question. But unfortunately still getting the error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Besides all errors in the test file, the only issue remains is that `module` is not an `optional`. To fix that, just change this:

```
public let unimodURL = Bundle.module?.url(forResource: "unimod", withExtension: "XML")
```

to:

```
public let unimodURL = Bundle.module.url(forResource: "unimod", withExtension: "xml")
```

---

## Update:

If you use `.xcodeproj` file, you will continue seeing this error. You should consider opening it with the `package.swift` or import it as a package (instead of converting it to a project)!

by the way, here is the generated file, so you can add it as a development asset when you are working with the xcodeproject:

```
import class Foundation.Bundle

private class BundleFinder {}

extension Foundation.Bundle {
    /// Returns the resource bundle associated with the current Swift module.
    static var module: Bundle = {
        let bundleName = "BioSwift_BioSwift"

        let candidates = [
            // Bundle should be present here when the package is linked into an App.
            Bundle.main.resourceURL,

            // Bundle should be present here when the package is linked into a framework.
            Bundle(for: BundleFinder.self).resourceURL,

            // For command-line tools.
            Bundle.main.bundleURL,
        ]

        for candidate in candidates {
            let bundlePath = candidate?.appendingPathComponent(bundleName + ".bundle")
            if let bundle = bundlePath.flatMap(Bundle.init(url:)) {
                return bundle
            }
        }
        fatalError("unable to find bundle named BioSwift_BioSwift")
    }()
}
```

Comment: I updated my question with the correct Package.swift file, but am still getting the error. With or without the `?`. Any other ideas what could be wrong? Is it maybe because I added the manifest file to an existing framework with an .xcodeproj file?

Comment: Get rid of the `xcodeproj` and open the `package.swift` directly. You can regenerate that xcodeproj when you need.

Comment: Not sure if I follow, how can I compile etc without an xcodeproj file?

Comment: Still confused, if there is no xcodeproj file, how do I open the project so I can build?

Comment: Double click on the package.swift

Comment: Ooh, I didn't realize you could do that. Opening it this way made the error go away.

Comment: If I open the package via package.swift, the error is gone, yes.

Comment: So why are you consist for opening it that way?

Comment: Because I didn't know I could open the package via package.swift. The project started as a .xcodeproj. Now I am adding SPM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223253/discussion-between-mojtaba-hosseini-and-koen).

Comment: I'm using the Package.swift directly, and still getting an error like that

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the instructions on this [video](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10169) you will see that you need to define how you would like to include non-clear purpose files in a package. In this case your package manifest should be something like:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "BioSwift",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries produced by a package, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "BioSwift",
            targets: ["BioSwift"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "BioSwift",
            dependencies: [],
            resources: [
              .copy("Resources")
            ]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "BioSwiftTests",
            dependencies: ["BioSwift"]),
    ]
)
```

Please pay attention on using Swift 5.3 tools and that you need to declare the resources for the respective target. The copy action on resources will leave them unprocessed when they are added in the compiled bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue (when i created fresh new package) ,what i did was i added new View file inside my package . And the error was gone .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I could solve it with the good ol' *"did you try to turn it off and back on again?"*.
No seriously, I simply used `Bundle.module` in my code (could also just be a one liner like `print(Bundle.module)`), closed Xcode completly and reopened the package via the `Package.swift` file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Resources folder path. It should be kept inside the Sources/PackageNameFolder/{Resources}. [image]

Answer (score 0):

What I did to access the `Bundle.module` object of my module outside of my Swift Package either in the app or another project was to create a publicly accessible variable inside the package i.e.

```
public static var myModuleNameBundle: Bundle { Bundle.module }
```

Replace the `myModuleName` of `myModuleNameBundle` with the name of your Swift Package

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue on .xcproject with local package added that includes `.process("Resources/")`. Simple Xcode restart fixed the issue.