# Image not showing in SwiftUI preview when using Swift Package Manager - works fine in Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swift-package-manager

I'm wondering if anyone got SwiftUI preview to work with a local image asset when using Swift Package Manager.

I'm not doing anything fancy. I have an asset catalog with a few images and my view looks like

```
public var body: some View {
    Image("star_5")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
}
```

When I create an Xcode project that depends on this swift package, I can reference the previews defined there and SwiftUI shows them correctly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you are inside a package, you need to pass in the `bundle`, because it is the `main` by default and there is no `main` in a  module.

So you need to use `.module` as the bundle:

```
Image("star_5", bundle: .module)
```

<sub>`.module` is an auto-generated resource. You don't need to manually write it!</sub>

---

#### Note

If you faced this error:

> Type 'Bundle' has no member 'module'

Follow **[this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63242343/5623035)** to make it automatically build for your package